# Как подключить файл с двумя type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, модули, babel

Вообщем, хочу подключить файл с модулями, а у браузеров есть особенность - нужно подключать так - `<script type="module"></script>` . Но, у меня есть проэкт на React , и нужно подключать еще Babel через type. Так вот , как подключить в файл два type , примерно так - `<script type="module text/babel"></script>`

Comment: Вроде никак https://stackoverflow.com/q/54018182/1016033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт не может иметь два `type`, один как - `type="module"`, а другой как - `type="text/babel"`. Насколько мне известно, запись вида `<script type="module text/babel"></script>` пока не поддерживается.

Сейчас у [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel) есть открытое issue:

- [Change `type` attribute to other to use with native esm type="module"](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone/issues/96)

и открытый пулл реквест на добавление изменений, связанный с данной проблемой:

- [Babel standalone type module](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/8410)
- [Babel standalone type module (Files changed)](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/8410/files)

Думаю, нужно подождать, пока появится решение для данного вопроса на GitHub.